# How to determine the date passing the Week Number and Day Number (Week) in java

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar, date-parsing

I need to get the date by passing these parameters

1. year
2. week number (in a month) i.e. 1,2,3,4,5
3. day number (in a week) 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday)
4. Month

I looked for a constructor in `Calendar` class but does not contain these parameters.

Comment: You can't get the date without a month.

Comment: I could not more strongly advise against using the `java.util.Calendar` class if you can possibly avoid it.  You should look at the `java.time` package and use the class appropriate for your use case.

Comment: How are your weeks of month counted? Does a new week begin on a Sunday, or on the 8th of the month, or?

Comment: The `Calendar` has long been supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid those troublesome, poorly designed, and flawed legacy date-time classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create date from year, week number and week's day use `java.util.Calendar` instance:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 26);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
```

To convert from `Calendar` to `java.util.Date` :

```
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

To convert `Date` into `java.time.LocalDateTime` use :

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: I replaced WEEK OF YEAR with WEEK OF MONTH AND MONTH and it was ok. Same results. Thanks!

Comment: If converting into java.time, use `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`. No point in purposely discarding timezone/offset information. Also, you should avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes as java.time was added to supplant them entirely. In this year of 2017, the other Answers by Ole V.V. or Hugo should have been accepted rather than this one.

Comment: I had the same problem that @Newb, and this example not resolve this big problem!

Answer (score 2):

In spite of your tags I agree with Joe C’s comment, you should prefer the modern Java date and time API (AKA known as `java.time` or JSR-310) over the long outdated `Calendar` and friends. The modern classes are more programmer friendly and nicer to work with, they come with fewer surprises, lead to clearer and more natural code (at least when you get used to the fluent style) and are easier to debug should you make a bug.

I don’t know how you count your weeks of the month. I have assumed that the first week starts on the first of the month and lasts 7 days (so the second week starts on the 8th and the 5th week on the 29th day of the month). If you count differently, please see [Hugo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44895004/5772882).

I suggest this method:

```
public static LocalDate weekNoAndDayToDate(Year year, Month month, int weekOfMonth, int dayOfWeek) {
    // find day of week: convert from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday)
    // to DayOfWeek, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)
    DayOfWeek dow;
    if (dayOfWeek == 0) { // Sunday
        dow = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
    } else {
        dow = DayOfWeek.of(dayOfWeek);
    }
    return year.atMonth(month)
            .atDay(1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dow))
            .with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekOfMonth);
}
```

With this we may do for example

```
    LocalDate today = weekNoAndDayToDate(Year.of(2017), Month.JULY, 1, 1);
```

This yields

```
2017-07-03
```

If you need either a `Date` or a `GregorianCalendar`, for example for an old API that you cannot change, do one of the following:

```
    Date oldfashiondDateObject
            = Date.from(today.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    GregorianCalendar oldfashionedCalendarObject
            = GregorianCalendar.from(today.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

In both cases the result will be different in different time zones (one of the inherent troubles of the old classes). On my computer the first yields a `Date` of

```
Mon Jul 03 00:00:00 CEST 2017
```

The second yields a `GregorianCalendar` equal to the same point in time.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Ole V.V. explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894241/7605325), you need to define in what day the week starts, and how many days it must have to be considered the first week.

For example, the ISO-8601 standard considers:

- Monday to be the first day-of-week.
- The minimal number of days in the first week: the standard counts the first week as needing at least 4 days

The month is divided into periods where each period starts on the defined first day-of-week. The earliest period in the same month is referred to as week `0` if it has less than the minimal number of days and week `1` if it has at least the minimal number of days.

Depending on how you define those, you can have different results. Consider the calendar for July 2017:

```
     July 2017
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31
```

If we consider ISO's definition, we have:

- week zero - 2017-07-01 to 2017-07-02
- week 1: from 2017-07-03 to 2017-07-09
- week 2: from 2017-07-10 to 2017-07-16
- week 3: from 2017-07-17 to 2017-07-22
- week 4: from 2017-07-23 to 2017-07-30
- week 5: 2017-07-31

If we consider first day of week as Sunday and minimal number of days in the first week as 1, we have:

- week 1: 2017-07-01
- week 2: from 2017-07-02 to 2017-07-08
- week 3: from 2017-07-09 to 2017-07-15
- week 4: from 2017-07-16 to 2017-07-21
- week 5: from 2017-07-22 to 2017-07-29
- week 6: from 2017-07-30 to 2017-07-31

---

As a solution with `Calendar` was already posted, I'm gonna write one using the new API. If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

I'm using a `DateTimeFormatter` because it takes all the fields (month, year, day of week and week of month) and resolves the day accordingly, creating a `LocalDate` (which has the day/month/year fields). I'm also using the `WeekFields` class, which can be configured to use different week definitions (first day and minimal number of days in first week)

There's also a little adjustment to consider Sunday as zero:

```
public LocalDate getDate(int weekOfMonth, int dayOfWeek, int month, int year) {
    // you can customize your week definition (first day of week and mininum days in first week)
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 2);
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        // week of month, using week definition from WeekFields
        .appendValue(wf.weekOfMonth()).appendPattern(" ")
        // day of week
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        // month and year
        .appendPattern(" M/yyyy")
        // create formatter
        .toFormatter();

    return LocalDate.parse(weekOfMonth + " " +
           // Sunday is 0, adjusting value
           (dayOfWeek == 0 ? 7 : dayOfWeek) + " " + month + "/" + year, fmt);
}
```

Using this code (week starts on Sunday, and 2 days are required to be considered the first week - otherwise week will be zero as in the first example above):

```
LocalDate d = getDate(1, 6, 7, 2017);
```

`d` will be `2017-07-08` (Saturday in the week 1 of July 2017).

If you want to use ISO 8601 definition, use the constant `WeekFields.ISO` instead of using `WeekFields.of()` method.

---

As [@Ole V.V. suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893620/how-to-determine-the-date-passing-the-week-number-and-day-number-week-in-java/44895004#comment76776912_44895004), it can also be done without creating a formatter: get the first `dayOfWeek` of the month and adjust it to the desired `weekOfMonth`:

```
public LocalDate getDate(int weekOfMonth, int dayOfWeek, int month, int year) {
    // you can customize your week definition (first day of week and mininum days in first week)
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 2);

    // Sunday is 0, adjusting value
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of(dayOfWeek == 0 ? 7 : dayOfWeek);

    // get the first weekday of the month
    LocalDate first = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dow));

    // check in which week this date is
    int week = first.get(wf.weekOfMonth());

    // adjust to weekOfMonth
    return first.plusWeeks(weekOfMonth - week);
}
```

This works exactly the same way, but without the need of a formatter - I've tested with dates from year 1600 to 2100 and it gets the same results.

---

PS: `Calendar` also has a similar configuration via the methods `setFirstDayOfWeek()` and `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`. You can check the default configuration calling the respective `get` methods.

Comment: Ah, the `WeekFields` class, of course. Thanks. Couldn’t it be done without building a string and parsing it? I think I would try getting the week number of the first Thursday of the month (for example; which day-of-week was required) using `WeekFields.weekOfMonth()`. Then add the appropriate number of weeks using `LocalDate.plusWeeks()`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I haven't tried without a formatter yet. Let's see if it works, I'll update the answer if I find a way. Thanks! - I used a formatter because it already resolves the day  based on the other fields,  but let's see if it can be done in another way...

Comment: @OleV.V. Done! Indeed, it's much better than using a formatter, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am very fond of the cooperation you and I are having, Hugo. Two minds think better than one.